# Drawer Navigation send data from Drawer.screen to drawerContent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here I am made a custom drawer in my application. but then I found a problem that I want to actually send data from my screen to custom drawer and reverse. is there a way to do it or I need to export that data.

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Main from "./screens/Main";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import Settings from "./screens/Settings";
import SwitchAccount from "./screens/Switch";
import Menu from "./screens/Menu";

function CustomDrawerContent() {
  return (
    <Menu/>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function MyContainer(){

  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Login"
        screenOptions={{
        drawerStyle:{width:275},
        headerShown:false, drawerPosition:"right"}}
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{swipeEnabled:false, headerShown:false}}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={Main}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Switch" component={SwitchAccount} options={{swipeEnabled:false, headerShown:false}}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Setting" component={Settings} options={{swipeEnabled:false, headerShown:false}}/>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why you cannot use the application state?

Comment: @MichaelBahl can you give me the documentation about that